# Pre-1948, what flags were found in American synagogues?

Tags: history, synagogue, geography

Certainly throughout the 1970s and 1980s, it was not at all uncommon to see an American synagogue where the Aron Kodesh was flanked by American and Israeli flags.

Pre-1948, was there just an American flag at the average synagogue? Or no flag at all? Or something else?

Comment: See also: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9283/did-shuls-in-europe-display-their-countries-flags-prior-to-the-holocaust

Comment: (I deleted my previous comment about what I'd seen, because it was in error.)

Comment: Rabbi Gedalia Anemer, zt'l, refused to allow flags anywhere in his shul's sanctuary.  He did not want to leave the impression that people were bowing down to a secular icon when they davened.

Comment: Rabbi Moshe Feinstein felt that a synagogue [at least he sanctuary; his son-in-law's shul has them outside the building, flanking the main entrance] simply wasn't the place for politics, only prayer. However a synagogue-built-as-such with flags is better than praying in someone's basement, according to Rabbi Feinstein. That's all moot here; it *was* common practice, so I'm asking about practice (not rabbinic views towards it).

Comment: In 1891 the Zionist Movement designed the flag, so it could have been used even before Israel declared independence.

Answer (score 6):

Lehavdil (about churches), a note at the bottom of [this page](http://www.witherspoonsociety.org/flags_in_church.htm) claims:

> In the United States the practice seems to have developed during the Taft administration when the world was heading toward WWI. Franklin Roosevelt issued a statement requesting churches to have the flag placed in churches as we entered WWII. My memory is that this was done reluctantly and at the advice of and pressure of Secretary of War Stimson.

So it may well be that much the same is true of synagogues.

Comment: A proclamation from the President about what houses of worship should do seems problematic with respect to the First Amendment. If it singled out Christian churches instead of all houses of worship, that's even more problematic. So, it probably referred to all houses of worship, including synagogues. I'm having trouble finding any more reliable evidence of this proclamation, though, at least via Google.

Comment: @Isaac: from the sound of it, it wasn't an official proclamation with the force of law behind it, just something that "patriotic Americans" should do, or something like that. I've found a couple references to this online, but all of them seem to be associated with various conspiracy theories about Freemasonry and whatnot; you're right, it would be nice to find something reliable.

Answer (score 4):

I always figured that the American Flag was only put up because the synagogues wanted to put up the Israeli Flag while still showing respect to the United States.

It appears that [it is not against the Flag Code](http://www.ushistory.org/betsy/faq.htm#q34) to fly a foreign flag without also flying an American Flag, but it does make sense not to open yourself up to criticism about favoring a foreign country over the one you're living in.

If so, the flags only started after Israel became a state (or [whenever the flag started being associated with Israel](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/9309/603)). I have no proof for this, however.

Answer (score 4):

I spoke to a person who was a teenager in the late 1930s. He said the Israeli flag was known as the Jewish flag then, and was in the Shuls even prior to 1948. As you can see from this link in Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Israel the flag was designed for the Zionist Movement in 1891. It became a Jewish symbol starting in late medieval Prague, and was adopted by the First Zionist Congress in 1897.

The question remains as to whether there were American flags alone in Shuls prior to this date.